# What are the pros and cons to styling each element with CSSModules versus using CSS child selectors?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, css-modules

I'm using react and styling components with bootstrap-sass and css-modules. When I want to style something, what are the pros and cons for individually styling elements like

```
<div className={styles.styleDiv}>
  <form className={styles.styleForm}>
    <input className={styles.styleInput></input>
  </form>
</div>
```

```css
.styleDiv {
  /* code */
}

.styleForm {
  /* code */
}

.styleInput {
  /* code */
}
```

rather than child selectors like

```
<div className={styles.styleDiv}>
  <form className={styles.styleForm}>
    <input></input>
  </form>
</div>
```

```
.styleDiv {
  /* code */
}

.styleForm {
  /* code */

  & > input {
    /* code */
  }
}
```

Is there a best-practice for how to use css modules?

Comment: Opinionated, but the second method unnecessarily couples possibly unrelated element styling, IMHO. I could see it also messing with CSS selector specificity if you wanted to override any styling.